# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, flask

I have an issue with Flask. Here's my code. I got the error
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:1351996@localhost:5432/example'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    person = Person.query.first
    return 'Hello ' + person.name
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I used `app.run(debug=True)` because I got another error when trying to run app using `FLASK_APP=app.py`, `flask run` and I don't know why this error appears to me!

Answer (score 2):

you're not actually executing the query. your index function should be

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    person = Person.query.first()
    return 'Hello ' + person.name
```

Note the parentheses after the .first